# Don't ressume after catching stalled event and reloading

Tags: javascript, html, audio, soundmanager2

When trying to play one song using soundmanager2 while another one is still loading, I get stalled status. This problem mostly happen on Mac Yosemite, but it is present on other browser/machines too.

> ```
> soundManager.play(soundId);
>
>         if(soundManager.sounds[soundId] != undefined)
>         {
> soundManager.sounds[soundId]._a.addEventListener("stalled",function(){
>                var audio = soundManager.sounds[soundId]._a;
>                soundManager.unload(soundId);
>                audio.load();
>                audio.play();
>             });
>         }
> ```

The console messages I got is this:

```
soundmanager2.js:1295 playSound3976: Ignoring abort
soundmanager2.js:1295 playSound3973: abort
soundmanager2.js:1295 playSound3973: waiting
soundmanager2.js:1295 playSound3976: Ignoring loadstart
soundmanager2.js:1295 playSound3976: Ignoring error
soundmanager2.js:1295 playSound3973: loadstart
soundmanager2.js:1295 playSound3973: stalled
soundmanager2.js:1295 playSound3973: unload()
soundmanager2.js:1295 playSound3973: Ignoring loadstart
soundmanager2.js:1295 playSound3973: Ignoring error
soundmanager2.js:1295 playSound3973: Ignoring play
soundmanager2.js:1295 playSound3973: Ignoring waiting
```